# Object Orientation Widget

Tags: origin, transform-orientation

I have a file that has 9 separate objects in it. In Object Mode if I set it to Global, Local, Normal, etc... it's all the same arrow direction. If I go into Edit Mode, set it to Normal on the orientation, they basically all have the correct orientation for each specific object. Why doesn't Object Mode have the same info for the orientation that Edit Mode has or how can I force Object Mode to have the correct arrow direction for each object. (Side note, each object has its own specific arrow direction)

[Example](https://gyazo.com/a0e7423bd43c12d241b670f3b07dee7c)

The reason why it needs to be in that specific orientation is so that it can rotate correctly when exported out... the correct rotation is what the Edit Mode normal has.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new Custom Transform Orientation per object, and name them to match. You will then be able to choose the custom transform as you also choose  Global/Local/Normal/etc. Object Mode deals with the object as a whole, so it won't give a good result using Normal for instance, where you might use that in edit mode as you make selections of individual elements of the object mesh.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I tried what you said and then I exported it out as a dae file. Tried the dae file in the program I needed it to be in, it still uses the default "global and/or normal" settings from Object Mode. Even when I make a new blender file and test with importing said dae file, the answer you've given doesn't help, still keeps it at the Object Mode settings. Question is, why can't Object Mode normal selection reflect the same results that Edit Mode normal has or is this just a broken feature in Blender? As I said, I need to export the file with the correct orientation.

Comment: If you are taking something out of Blender and into something else, you will only ever get global orientation. If you even successfully create custom orientations in a blender file, they are not capable of being exported or appended to other files. I have to create secondary plane objects to import along with my rigged character to repeat the process of creating custom orientations.